# script in start up as background process

Tags: linux

I want to put a bash script i created into the start up script, but I want this script to fork / allow me to use the system normally as the script runs in the background. This script has to trigger, this one script contains references to other scripts also (if that is important).

Distro: linaro (ubuntu based FS) 13.9

So I want collective.sh to run in the start up ..

collective.sh runs:

```
./firewall.sh
sleep 5
./checkIfaces
```

How would i go about doing this? running it as a service also so I am able to stop it half way through if needed (this script will run for 5 hours so I need to interrupt it incase of emergencies)

Comment: what distro and release version are you using?

Comment: oh sorry edited for this information!

Comment: I would suggest to check how other services are managed and implement similar way. Eg with Upstart or systemd or sysv shell scripts or something else.

Comment: @nkts I have tried upstart but it ran the script before allowing access to shell :( I need this access I cannot wait 5 hours to access the shell xD

Answer (score 1):

Place the file in /etc/rc.d/init.d; The script will be executed on next reboot.

Comment: I am a bit of a noob, can you tell me how to do this, will this fork it? will this allow me to stop it by running service /etc/init.d/collective.sh stop ?

Comment: Yes, you can start and stop this as /etc/init.d/yourScript.sh start/stop